# What happened to my Windows XP drive

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-xp

I'm updating my new server, during that update, I need to update my old Intel E5200, Dual Core, 2 GB, dual 250 GB drives, Windows XP Pro SP3. Tired of Microsoft I decided to explore Linux (Ubuntu 14).

I proceeded to install, not clear on the partition thing, with two 250 GB SATA IDE Drives, I disabled my primary in the BIOS and disconnected its data cable. I continued to install Ubuntu and assigned the core/swap partitions. Couldn't have loaded any easier.

When completed I enabled the primary drive in BIOS and reconnected the Data cable. My intention was to have two separate drives with independent OS's, Windows XP and Linux, being able to switch in BIOS either drive for desired OS. I need XP for process control debugging for GPIB.

So After completion I rebooted and attempted to switch to my Primary drive with XP and found I wasn't able to access that drive, as though Ubuntu actually installed on both drives. Unable to access my Windows XP drive completely.

Is there a link which can direct me to explain what happened? I have a complete library of programs and reading files needed on the Windows XP Drive I would like to recover. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be due to Bios settings in your machine. please check whether your XP machine drive shows in the "Computer management -> Disk Management" or not.

Answer (score -1):

Very good!  I like a man who thinks like I do and PHYSICALLY DISCONNECTS drives for safety.  Around here I'm oft treated like I'm some sort of a nut, but I too believe in safety.

Rest assured, provided that you actually disconnected the correct drive, everything is going to be fine.  Of course if you disconnected the blank drive and formatted the windows drive... there's no going back, but I'm going to hope for the best.

What I believe happened is that when Ubuntu installed on the blank drive, it installed its own boot sector on that drive, and for some reason, your bios is preferring to boot to that drive.  In my opinion, you have THREE GREAToptions.

1) You can use your bios' own "Boot Menu" (most bios have them these days.  sometimes you have to press a key such as escape or f12 at boot time).  The problem with this plan is that it doesn't actually protect you from rampant viruses which can literally reach out and wipe your drives.  If it's connected, it's game.

2) You can do things the way I do them, with a [removable hard drive system](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KS8S9W) such as this one so that there is only one hard drive connected at a time.  Trust me, this is really your best bet if you like safety!  Windows can reach out and hurt things.  I've experienced it first hand!

3) You can do things in a somewhat more normal way, which works very much like partitioned hard drives in so much as you select boot media from a menu at boot time, with both drives connected at once and no switching of anything in the bios.  Best of all this solution is EASY and doesn't cost anything.  You just [open this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), burn the self booting CD, and shut down the PC.  If you have not already done so, connect both hard drives such that they are both recognized by the computer.  Then you boot your computer to the boot repair CD, and follow its easy one click operation to repair your boot.  When it is done, your computer should present you with a sort of menu at boot time offering you the choice of Ubuntu (at the top) and Windows (usually at or near the bottom).  By default it usually boots to Ubuntu first.